# iOS keychain, store more kSecValueData items

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using a keychainwrapper which works with ARC, and with this you can store a password into the keychain with the following code:

```
[keychainItem setObject:InputField.text forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
```

And get it out with:

```
NSString *loc_pwd1 = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge NSString*)kSecValueData];
```

As I understand the kSecValueData means that the value will be encrypted, but what if I wanna store more encrypted values, can you store with some kind of identifier, so you can have several kSecValueData elements.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your key is associated to one entry in the keychain. You could store an `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` (depending of your situation) instead of directly storing the `inputField.text`. So if you need to add more values to the object of that key, you would simply have to add it to the dictionary/array.

I also recently used the iOS keychain, and I picked up [SSKeychain](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain), it looks a bit more straightforward than yours, worth a look! (I'm not saying the one you use is bad, just letting you know what worked for me :P)

Comment: You could also look into Lockbox, a great keychain wrapper.